# How to loop over a large SQL result set in Java or get X number of rows at a time

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-batch

In my **Spring Batch** program I execute a **SQL** query, grab some information off the returned result set, then print it out to a file.

There are too many rows returned so the query has bad performance.

```
SELECT * 
FROM CIF
WHERE status > 1
```

This example query returns 500,000 rows.

I've tried selecting the top 5,000 rows at a time:

```
SELECT TOP 5000
FROM CIF
WHERE status > 1
```

The problem here is if I loop over this, I'll get the same 5,000 rows each time. I can't think of a way to loop and get 5,000 rows, print the info I need to a file, and grab the next 5,000 rows. Any ideas?

Comment: Define `bad performance` Maybe you should fix first why getting 500.000 rows performs bad. One option is to query all 500.000 and when you loop it write to file every 5000 rows.

Comment: I get the 500,000 rows quickly but can't store that many rows into memory in Java, it just can't handle an object that large. I have to query the database for 5,000 rows at a time, I can't fetch all 500,000 and loop over that.

Comment: Getting 5000 rows at a time is however dangerous, what if the number of rows changes while you are doing this ? 500.000 is not that big however, maybe you should find out why it performs so bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about spring batch but as far you use sql you should be able to use the ["limit"](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/select_limit.php) parameter.

Comment: That won't work. I need to get 5,000 of the 500,000 records with each pass. If I simply set LIMIT to 5,000, I will get the same 5,000 rows each time the query executes.

Comment: In my opinion 500.000 records is not that much. How big is one record?

Comment: Did you see that limit offers an offset parameter?

Comment: Yes I see the offset parameter, but once again, how would I craft the query to offset X number of rows as to go through each 500,000 rows? If I say

`SELECT *
FROM CIF
ORDER BY STATUS
OFFSET 5,000 ROWS` it will not return each 5,000 rows

Comment: One record is very large. In our application we have a max return count of 15,001 rows. If any more rows are returned we exit the program.

Comment: how important is performance? Is more important than data integrity?

Comment: I don't understand the line of questioning.

Comment: If one query execution needs a lot of time how do you make sure other parts of the data are not changed while you wait for the execution? or if data is changed that you've already got while getting another chunk?

Comment: I don't think I'm explaining this well enough for you. One query execution does not take a lot of time. That's why I'm obtaining 5,000 rows at a time..it executes in milliseconds. I don't need help analyzing these parts of the program, this was not part of my original question.

Comment: Because I can't load 500,000 records into memory.

Comment: Back to the limit. Can't you put save the current offset in a variable and to multiple query passing the offset with the param. In your answer you hardcoded the 5000

Comment: Yes that is a good idea. That is something along the lines of what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch does this natively with our `JdbcPagingItemReader`.  You can also stream records (instead of returning them all at once) with the `JdbcCursorItemReader`.  The paging one handles generating the limit queries for you.  You can read more about the `JdbcPagingItemReader` in the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#pagingItemReaders